# KQL regex row extraction

Tags: kql

I have a column called AdditionalExtensions that contains the following start=Aug 13 2022 20:42:17;logver700060366.ad

I want to add a regex search to this to only extract and display the date and time as following: Aug 13 2022 20:42:17

I dont care about the rest of the information in that column.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: nothing really, I have tried reading over regex and adding my own statements but no luck

Comment: Aren't we taking about extracting the text between the `=` and `;` characters?

Comment: yes correct i only want the text Aug 13 2022 20:42:17 to be displayed

Comment: Please note that you've been given an answer 2 week ago.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseoperator) operator (option 1) would probebly be the cleanest way to go here.
I added some more options for educational purposes.

```
print txt = "start=Aug 13 2022 20:42:17;logver700060366.ad"
| parse txt with * "=" dt1 ";" *                                                                    // option 1
| extend dt2 = extract("=(.*?);", 1, txt)                                                           // option 2
| extend dt3 = split(split(txt, ";")[0], "=")[1]                                                    // option 3
| extend dt4 = trim("^.*?=|;.*$", txt)                                                              // option 4
| extend dt5 = substring(txt, indexof(txt, "=")  + 1, indexof(txt, ";") - indexof(txt, "=") - 1)    // option 5
```

| txt | dt1 | dt2 | dt3 | dt4 | dt5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| start=Aug 13 2022 20:42:17;logver700060366.ad | Aug 13 2022 20:42:17 | Aug 13 2022 20:42:17 | Aug 13 2022 20:42:17 | Aug 13 2022 20:42:17 | Aug 13 2022 20:42:17 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA63QzWrDMAwH8Ptg7yDEDnGWpv5IU2gwY89ROsgWLzN0SXDULYc+/OR1F8NurQ8CGeOf/pqCHwhoIbCAM7WB7POpB2VAS6257Cq9U9vmOPZfLmyllLU0dV22nVXa4P3dGaY2zO73i29PH5ADWoSOFGCD3N3grNcwTuTHAVQE3UJu6JjQPDQ3oX2jDG1W5k+iwQJUEacRNwF1AhoG5+noKbtUZooYU+zloYi5xV4drgNNAlYMUvCfGb5wOntuyvwBr46XgFUCbmLC0+vM6NBf8vmhc8v4/heWMwI8xh2n97wEWP3zdgVKpODmB6B2LR10AgAA)